# C# HttpClient - GET - Parse response and assert

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation, dotnet-httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to make a GET call and I want to parse the JSON response and assert the key value pairs.

This is my code:

```
public partial class EntityClass
{
    [JsonProperty("StatusCode")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }

    // more code
}
```

```
using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"Domain\user", "password");
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://baseURL");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/apiendpoint")
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string responsebody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityClass>(responsebody);
                    
                }
            }
```

I can assert the response like this

```
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
```

However I want to assert each Key Value pair in the JSON response. I can't get it to work with the above code
How can I access the key value pair and assert?

For example if the JSON Response is:

```
{
StatusCode:200,
Key1: Value1,
Key2: Value2
}
```

I want to be able to assert like

```
Assert.AreEqual(200,data.StatusCode);
Assert.AreEqual(Value1, data.Key1);
Assert.AreEqual(Value2, data.Key2);
```

However in my code `response.StatusCode` returns OK and not 200.

Comment: The "responsebody" in your code will not contain the response code.  The response code is a property of HttpResponseMessage, not HttpResponseMessage.Content.  You could add it manually after the rest of it has been created from the deserialization call.

Comment: Do you want to assert that properties of a object parsed from json have specific values (what properties and what values?) or do you want to convert `HttpResponseMessage` to  json and assert some properties and values (which ones?) on that?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek for example if the response is {StatusCode: 200, Key1: Value, Key2: Value} I want to be able to assert each value separately depending on the requirement

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek i added more detail. when i assert response.StatusCode the value is OK and not 200

Comment: Based on your edit: There are no `Value1` or `Value2` properties on `HttpResponse`. Are you sure your last code snippet should not contain `data` instead of `response`? Since `data` is the parsed response json body whilst `response` is the abstract HTTP response which happens to also have `StatusCode` property.

Comment: Yes Sorry i edited it again. Sorry new to HttpClient and C#.

Comment: Ok, so you receive a json response over HTTP, deserialize it into .NET object and want to assert that the contents of the json are present in the deserialized object? Could you please confirm that this is what you're attempting to do? If yes, what problem are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: as a best practice, you should make sure the response is a "good response". do not assume 200, 202, etc. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode?view=net-5.0

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek yes exactly. I work in test automation so i am creating automated tests to confirm that we receive a status code 200 and confirm that other values are returned. pretty basic as we don't have much APIs to test right now but i want it to be scaleable so i can reuse code going forward

Comment: I believe that assertions should be specific to a given test, not global. It seems to me that you would be testing the serialization library and not the API here. You might have some sort of assert that checks all properties for being non-null through reflection but even that would be test-specific, as in some cases, APIs would be allowed to produce objects with empty properties.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek how would you suggest i assert the response either directly or via serialisation library?

Comment: No need for that JsonProperty attribute

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters noted, the status code is not part of the body, but you appear to be handling that part correctly.

To get to the key/value pairs as you call them, you can parse the string into an intermediate representation, and then iterate over the properties of that representation. This avoids having to have the native .NET type that would normally be populated, which may be preferable to avoid having the automation test depend on a specific type.

So, it depends on which serializer you can or have to use. Since I see `JsonConvert` in your code you're using Newtonsoft's code. In that case use [JObject.Parse()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
var expectedValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var responsebody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var root = JObject.Parse(responsebody);

foreach (var property in root.Properties)
{
    // not tested, but you get the idea...
    var expectedValue = expectedValues[property.Name];
    if (expectedValue == null)
        // null has to be checked via token type
        Assert.IsTrue(property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Null);
    else
        // check they are same type AND value
        Assert.AreEqual(property.Value.ToObject(expectedValue.GetType()), expectedValue);
}
```

The trick here is that you need to create a dictionary that maps expected keys to expected values, and then check these values against what's in the intermediate representation.
This can be used to prove that no unexpected key is in the output (because there would be no dictionary entry) and to prove that for the keys returned, their values are expected.

To also prove there are no missing keys, you can check the keys of the dictionary against the names of the returned properties.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the import statements?

Comment: Don't know all of them off the top of my head but added Newtonsoft.

Comment: The issue with no import statements and the (over?) use of "var"....it makes it much harder for someone to copy and paste "working" code.  #justSaying

Comment: @granadaCoder SO is not a code-writing service, and the use of `var` is a religious war no one will win. As in all programming, there are tradeoffs and really cool ways to shoot yourself in the foot.